# What is the current way to import 3rd party JS node modules for the browser?

Tags: typescript

There are a ton of questions and answers about this topic but I can't seem to find an up-to-date answer.

I want to use the module `hyperscript` which is installed locally in node_modules. It has no d.ts file.

I can create one, which I believe should look like:

```
declare module 'hyperscript' {
    export default function H(...a: any[]) : HTMLElement;
}
```

I put that in src/typings/hyperscript.d.ts, which typescript seems to pick up.

My ts source file has:

```
import H from 'hyperscript';

const element = H('h1', "This is a title");
```

I compile & bundle with:

```
browserify --debug src/main.ts -p [ tsify --noImplicitAny ] > js/bundle.js
```

This all goes well, however when I try to run in the browser, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: hyperscript_1.default is not a function
```

I'm pretty sure hyperscript outputs just one default function because in plain JS with babel/browserify, I use:

```
import H from 'hyperscript';
```

And it works fine.

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "hyperscript-example-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hyperscript typescript example",
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "hyperscript": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "latest",
    "tsify": "latest",
    "uglifyjs": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify --debug src/main.ts -p [ tsify --noImplicitAny ] > js/bundle.js"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "outDir": "js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": false
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/typings/**/*.d.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Hacking away at this some more, it looks like the only way to do this is to re-write my import as:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/hyperscript.d.ts" />
import _H = require('hyperscript'); // Gets no type info from my d.ts file
const H: (...a: any[]) => HTMLElement = _H as any;
```

The TypeScript handbook says I should be able to use standard import syntax with 3rd party JS node_modules. Quoting from [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

```
/// <reference path="node.d.ts"/>
import * as URL from "url";
let myUrl = URL.parse("http://www.typescriptlang.org");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration files are basically the developer attempting to explain the ambient world to TypeScript ([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html))

In your case the declaration :

```
declare module 'hyperscript' {
    export default function H(...a: any[]) : HTMLElement;
}
```

Is actually wrong. The function `H` is not a *default* export. It is *the main export*. So what you want is really:

```
declare module 'hyperscript' {
    export = function H(...a: any[]) : HTMLElement;
}
```